# polynom.sty: How can show only the task and the result of a Polynomial long division?

Tags: math-mode, polynom, polynomials

How can I ***automatically*** show only the task and the result of a Polynomial long division, like

[image]

(without the 'gap', too late seen above)

I know, there are possibilities to bunch that together (*see MWE*), but there is a problem with the remainder:

[image]

**Maybe, there is a clever method for the remainder an it's  sign ('+' or '-') or it has to be filtered out from `polynom.sty` or there is a possibility I do not know.**

So my question is: How can I show only

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{polynom, xcolor}

\begin{document}
% Save some polynoms
\polyadd{\NumeratorI}{3x^4 - 22x^3 + 39x^2 - \frac{41}{2}x + \frac{11}{2}}{0}%
\polyadd{\NumeratorII}{x^2-10x+25}{0}%
\polyadd{\Denominator}{x-5}{0}%

\textbf{Target:}  This without showing the calculation \\
\polylongdiv[style=C]\NumeratorI\Denominator   \\
\polylongdiv[style=B]\NumeratorI\Denominator   \\

\textbf{Actual:} Do it by your own \\
\polydiv\QuotientWithoutRemainderI\NumeratorI\Denominator
$\displaystyle 
\left( \polyprint\NumeratorI \right) :  \left( \polyprint\Denominator \right) 
= 
\polyprint\QuotientWithoutRemainderI+\frac{\polyprint{\polyremainder}}{\polyprint\Denominator}$ \\

{\color{red} Problem:} \\
\polydiv\QuotientWithoutRemainderII\NumeratorII\Denominator 
$\displaystyle 
\left( \polyprint\NumeratorII \right) :  \left( \polyprint\Denominator \right) 
= 
\polyprint\QuotientWithoutRemainderI+\color{red}\frac{\polyprint{\polyremainder}}{\polyprint\Denominator}$ \\
\end{document}
```

[image]